# input a variable name and display - BATCH FILE

Tags: batch-file

I wanted the user insert a variable and then be displayed with echo It would be something like %%var%%
 A variable inside another variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set var=value
set x=var
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo !%x%!
...
endlocal
```

This should outperfrom the `call` approach.

Comment: to outperform the `call`, you shoud remove the `call`;)

Comment: @Stephan  - aggh yes.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I hope I got your question right. You need an additional parse-phase. this can be done with `call`:

```
set var=value
set x=var
call echo %%%x%%%
REM on commandline: call echo %%x%%
```

(yes, that's ugly, but it works)