# Batch - How to Echo %%Variable%%

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd, echo

I have a small problem with a batch file I'm working on.

Here's a simple sample:

I would like to get the string "THERE" as my result.
But the result I get is just "HELLO"

```
set hello=there
set a=h
set b=ello 
set result=%a%%b%
echo %result%
```

I already tried something like this:

```
Echo %%result%%
```

And Sadly, it just gets me the result %HELLO%
Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: duplicate. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28453453/2152082) are two working solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that `%%result%%` gives you `%result%` on the output is that the `%%` tokens are interpreted *first,* and further interpretation is not done.

However, you can use that to your advantage, doing a *second* level of indirection with the following trick:

```
@echo off
set result=hello
echo %result%
call :iset second %%result%%
echo %second%
goto :eof

:iset
    for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`echo %%%2%%`) do set %1=%%i
    goto :eof
```

The secret lies in passing the thing you want interpreted (in this case, `%%result%%` passes in the literal `%result%` as per the rules stated in the first paragraph, *not* the interpretation of it).

The `for` loop then echos the interpretation of that (`hello`) surrounded by `%...%` (again, the double `%%` reduces to `%`), so that *it* is also interpreted, and it uses that to set the target variable you also passed in.

The upshot is that it effectively gives you:

```
%(%result%)%
```

which is what you're after.

---

Might I suggest, however, that you start looking into Powershell, so that you don't have to perform these batch-gymnastics in future :-)

Comment: This worked. Thanks for sharing this tip! And, sure, I'll look into powershell. Thanks for the support. All the best.