# How to Reassess Batch variables?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Is it possible to reassess Batch variables?

Here an example what i want to do :

```
set a=Hello
set b=%a%
set a=Bye
echo %b% 
rem Here, i want to show 'Bye' instead of 'Hello'
```

Comment: You can do indirection with batch variables but it's not that pretty: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28578290/batch-how-to-echo-variable/28578431#28578431

Comment: Thank you for reducing your problem to the simplest terms while still showing example code demonstrating the behavior you expect.  +1!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use delayed expansion to pass by reference.

```js
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "a=Hello"
set "b=a"
set "a=Bye"

echo !%b%!
```

... should output `Bye`.  You're setting `b` to the variable *name* of `a` with this method.  In the `echo` line, the batch thread first gets the value of `b`, which is `a`.  It then expands the value of `!a!` via delayed expansion.

Be advised that if your values are likely to contain exclamation marks, you probably need to limit `enabledelayedexpansion` to the retrieval of your values only, avoiding having it active during the variable setting.

```js
set "a=Hello"
set "b=a"
set "a=Bye"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
echo !%b%!
endlocal
```

Answer (score 3):

You may store in variable `b` a *reference* to the value in `a`, and then use Delayed Expansion to access it:

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Store in "b" a *reference* to the value in "a"
set b=!a!

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set a=Hello
echo Show the value in a: %b%
set a=Bye
echo Show the value in a: %b%
```